# How do I "mass edit" a field in my mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my users table and I want to change about 1000 entries from "null" to a specific zip code... is there a query I can run?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to preview what's getting updated first:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE specificfield IS NULL
```

The update script is as simple as:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET specificfield='$newvalue' WHERE specificfield IS NULL
```

**Where:**
yourtable - the name of the table you want with cells you want to update.
specificfield - the name of the field you'd like to update.
$newvalue - the new value for the field (in quotes since it's likely a string - my need to escape that string).

**note::** this only works if all the fields are going to get the *same value* (eg. specificfield='00000')

**Updated:** (per user comments)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE (specificfield IS NULL OR specificfield=0) AND userid<1000

UPDATE yourtable SET specificfield='$newvalue' 
WHERE (specificfield IS NULL OR specificfield=0) AND userid<1000
```

The where statement from your a select is the same as used in the update - so you can tailor a where statement for exactly the conditions you need.

Comment: ok this works bc all the existing fields are null or 0 (i can do it 2x)... what if i want to limit further to just a specific set of users... do i just add "and WHERE userid < 1000" or somethign?

Comment: Almost - I've updated the `select` + `update` lines in the code above - you can complete both updates with one command (`OR`) and include further filters

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 37
STR: =/
SQL: SELECT * FROM 'users'
WHERE (Willing=/0) AND userid<1000

SQL query: 

SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE (Willing=/0) AND userid<1000

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'
WHERE (Willing=/0) AND userid<1000' at line 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM 'users'
WHERE (Willing=/0) AND userid<1000  the value im trying to change is "/0" (not sure how it got that way int he first place)  only zero or one was an option

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE Willing=0 AND userid<1000` if willing is a numeric field otherwise: `SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE Willing='0' AND userid<1000` if it's a string field

Answer (score 2):

The following will update a field in all the rows, where the field is currently set to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET    your_field_name = 'ZIP CODE' 
WHERE  your_field_name IS NULL;
```

Simply substitute the `'ZIP CODE'` value with the string that you require.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `fieldname` = 'ZIPCODE' WHERE `fieldname` is null;
```

Comment: That's not going to work, unless he's using the literal string "null."

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = 'ZIPCODE' WHERE fieldname IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for those that's field value is not null this might be the right approach.

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 'NEW_VALUE' WHERE columnname = 'OLD_VALUE';
```